# PHP - Limit number of invoices by user based on subscription package

Tags: php, mysql

i'm building this CRM system which providing small business owners to manage their clients & billing.

on my system there is 3 subscription packages

1. Free (30 days)
2. Gold (1 year)
3. Silver (6 months)

free - free package is available for users with no price & users on this package will be able to manage 3 clients & 12 invoices.

Gold - gold users package is a paid  one & users on gold package will be able to manage unlimited clients & invoices.

Siliver - paid package, 50 clients & 100 invoices

what i need to know is how can i limit the number of invoices & clients created  by a user using php & MYSQL

i would like if some one can explain me in detals.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, whenever a user clicks on the 'create new invoice' or 'create new client' button, you count how many exist already. If more than allowed, tell the user he needs to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table in your database and log the number of invoices and clients remaining for each user. Then every time your users create either a client or an invoice, you check if there are invoices remaining and decrement accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replys Sylverdrag & Konerak can you guys provide me some example with php code do this

Comment: Sure. Can you please post the code that creates a new invoice or a new client? We'll add the check.

Comment: I agree with Konerak, it would be best if you post the relevant bits of your code and ideally, the structure of your database.